# Matplotlib's GUI doesn't allow typing in save box?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been using matplotlib in python for some time now and I've finally gotten around to asking this question about an issue on my mac. When a plot shows up (after the `plot()` command, `draw()`, or `show()`), I have all the functionality I could want; I can move, zoom, etc. that I didn't do in the code.

When I go to save a figure with the view as I desire the save as box opens up and prompts for a filename. Anything I type appears in the terminal I used to execute the command! Selecting X11 and then typing has same result. Nothing seems to put the keyboards output into that box, but I can paste into the box using the mouse->Paste action and I can select files in the menu to overwrite and it works fine.

What's up with this?

### Update:

The problem was wonderfully outlined and now has some solutions posted [in this post: Why doesn't the save button work on a matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692928/why-doesnt-the-save-button-work-on-a-matplotlib-plot)

Comment: Which backend is this? It sounds like you should file a bug report in matplotlib's tracker.

Comment: I have tried to get matplotlib running so I can reproduce your issue and try to fix it, but I haven't gotten it working so far.  I'll keep trying as I have free time, though. :-)

Comment: Thanks Benson; keep it alive!

Answer (score 1):

Just installed matplotlib 0.99.1 on Python 2.6.2 on Snow Leopard and ran the following code:

```
from pylab import *
plot([1,2,3])
show()
```

Then, I fiddled around with the plot for a while and clicked the save button. The save dialog box popped up normally and allowed me to save (and type) fine. This was using the TkAgg backend. However, I did get this error:

```
2009-12-08 00:40:18.772 Python[728:60f] -deltaZ is deprecated for NSEventTypeMagnify.  Please use -magnification.
```

Which seems to be something to do with Snow Leopard changing some APIs.

Sorry for using typing this as a post instead of a comment, but code tags aren't allowed in comments :(