# Why doesn't the save button work on a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtualenv

I have [matplotlib 1.0.0](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) installed in a Python 2.7 virtualenv on Mac OS X 10.6. I can create plots fine. However, whenever I press the *Save* button, I can't type text into the save dialog window nor can I save the plot. The only thing I can do is hit cancel. Any thoughts on what's causing this and how to fix it?

[image]

### Matplotlib installation procedure

I installed matplotlib by cloning [astraw's matplotlib github repository](http://github.com/astraw/matplotlib) and then loosely following [HyperJeff's Installation Instructions for numpy/scipy/matplotlib](http://blog.hyperjeff.net/?p=160). Below are the potentially relevant sections of `setup.cfg` and `make.osx`, including the sections that I modified prior to compiling and installing.

#### setup.cfg

```
[egg_info]
tag_svn_revision = 1

[directories]
basedirlist = /Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/matplotlib-test

[status]
#suppress = True
#verbose = True

[provide_packages]

[gui_support]
#gtk = False
#gtkagg = False
#tkagg = False
wxagg = False
#macosx = False

[rc_options]
backend = MacOSX
#numerix = numpy
```

#### make.osx

```
# build mpl into a local install dir with
PREFIX=/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/matplotlib-test
MPLVERSION=1.0rc1
PYVERSION=2.7
PYTHON=python${PYVERSION}
ZLIBVERSION=1.2.3
PNGVERSION=1.2.39
FREETYPEVERSION=2.3.11
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6
OSX_SDK_VER=10.6
ARCH_FLAGS="-arch i386-arch x86_64"

## You shouldn't need to configure past this point (but I did...)

PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig"
CFLAGS="${ARCH_FLAGS} -I${PREFIX}/include -I${PREFIX}/include/freetype2 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX${OSX_SDK_VER}.sdk"
LDFLAGS="${ARCH_FLAGS} -L${PREFIX}/lib -syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX${OSX_SDK_VER}.sdk"

PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig"
CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I${PREFIX}/include -I${PREFIX}/include/freetype2 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX${OSX_SDK_VER}.sdk"
LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -L${PREFIX}/lib -syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX${OSX_SDK_VER}.sdk"
FFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
```

After modifying `setup.cfg` and `make.osx`, I issued the following commands to install matplotlib:

```
make -f make.osx fetch deps mpl_build mpl_install
python setup.py install
```

*Note:* `sudo` isn't required, since I'm installing into a virtualenv instead of into the site-packages like HyperJeff is doing.

### Python Installation

I installed Python 2.7 using python.org's *Python 2.7 PPC/i386/x86-64 Mac OS X Installer Disk Image for Mac OS X 10.5*. Thanks to [Ned Deily's answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472349/what-are-the-differences-between-the-two-python-2-7-mac-os-x-disk-image-installer/3472625#3472625), I know that this version of Python 2.7 cannot run IDLE or Tkinter on Mac OS X 10.6.

### Questions

1. Could the version of Python 2.7 that I have installed be the cause of the problem? Should I reinstall Python 2.7 using the *Python 2.7 32-bit Mac OS X Installer Disk Image for Mac OS X 10.3 through 10.6*?
2. Is there a different `gui_support` option that I need to configure in `setup.cfg` and then recompile matplotlib?

### Update, September 13, 2010, 3:33 PM

It appears that other Mac OS X and matplotlib users are having the same problem. In the matplotlib-users mailing list, [two users reported having the same problem on Mac OS X 10.5](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_name=3E234DB6-BD55-4F95-803E-EF0806E80371%40gmail.com). Although, they were running matplotlib 0.99.1.1 and 0.99.1.2 versus matplotlib 1.0.0 that I have installed.

### Updated, September 14, 2010, 8:18 AM

[matplotlib bug  2973874](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2973874&group_id=80706&atid=560720) was opened on 20-Mar-10 with the same issue. However, it's a priority 5 and hasn't been modified since the bug was originally opened. Below is the description from the bug:

> I am running the 6.0.1 enthought python distibution 64bit Mac. If a run a plot and click save I get a save dialog window that opens, I canot enter text in the file name field. I can select an existing file but still cannot modify the name. If I select a non png file it does not overwrite it. I get a file with the same name but with the png extension.

Comment: For reference, my stock 2.6 Python (for 10.6) and matplotlib 1.0 doesn't have this problem. No help there, sad to say.

Comment: @Andrew — How did you install matplotlib? Also, don't sell your comment short—it's a valid data point. The fact that matplotlib works under the stock Python 2.6, could point toward the Python 2.7 framework with broken Tkinter support as the culprit.

Comment: I experienced the same issue running Python 2.7 in virtualenv in 10.7. The answer below fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @AndrewDalke was yours through a virtualenv or using system python?

Comment: That was the system Python. I also have Python 2.7, compiled directly into /usr/local/, and that doesn't have a problem.

Comment: @AndrewDalke,  System python should be unaffected by this, good to confirm it!

Comment: I'm using python-2.7.3 (via pythonbrew), with pip-installed matplotlib-1.1.0, on OS X 10.6.8, and I most definitely *do* have this annoying problem. I'm not using virtualenv so I don't think the solution below is helpful to me. Still investigating...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convince OSX that the virtualenv is actually running from an Application Bundle.  Fix discussed here:

http://groups.google.com/group/python-virtualenv/browse_thread/thread/83fa4a12d22a30c8/744e19c194f1618a

And implemented here:

https://github.com/gldnspud/virtualenv-pythonw-osx

Comment: what is the 'env_path' in this script @thouis?

Comment: I believe it's the path to the virtualenv.

Comment: Hm.  I am not seeing any '.Python' dir in my ``~/virtualenvs``.

Comment: Odd.  What version of virtualenv are you using?  I'm on 1.5.1.

Comment: thouis, it was because my venv was based on the ``brew install`` (non Framework) version of python, not the system one.  I have rolled in the method you link to at https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/54

Comment: Worked great for me. OS X Lion, python 2.7.2 built from source as a framework, matplotlib from source.

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar problem and I wanted to implement this solution.
So I tried to run the install_pythonw.py like this:
laura$ python install_pythonw.py `which python`/../..

and I got:

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/.Python does not exist; exiting.

any idea? I am using a mac with snow Leopard and EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My answer doesn't fix the problem but can workaround it easily! You can touch a new file with the correct file extension in a terminal. After you can choose this file with the mouse inside the matplotlib window and overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this:

Use `conda install python.app` to install `pythonw`.

Then use `pythonw` instead of `python` in your terminal.

E.g.

```
pythonw my_plot.py
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For those that Thouis method didn't work:

I noticed that a simple work around is to change matplotlib backend. Here is a list of available backends:

http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Note that you should choose one of the renderer ones (i.e. the ones that support `show()` command). You might need to install the backend, but you might have multiple ones installed.

To do so:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')    #replace 'Qt4Agg' with desired backend
```

Warning: This should be done BEFORE importing pylab, etc.