# Setting basedirlist in setup.cfg and PREFIX in make to point to virtualenv

Tags: python, makefile, virtualenv, setuptools

In [SO question 3692928](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692928/why-doesnt-the-save-button-work-on-a-matplotlib-plot), I showed how I compiled and installed matplotlib in a virtualenv. One thing I did was suboptimal though—I manually set the `basedirlist` in setup.cfg and `PREFIX` in make.osx.

#### setup.cfg

```
[directories]
basedirlist = /Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/matplotlib-test
```

#### make.osx

```
PREFIX=/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/matplotlib-test
```

Is there a way that I can automatically set these to the currently activated virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable:

**setup.cfg**

```
[directories]
basedirlist = ${VIRTUAL_ENV}
```

**make.osx**

```
PREFIX=${VIRTUAL_ENV}
```